# Error listing files in a directory with Sinatra

Tags: css, ruby, directory, sinatra

I'm trying to follow along with this Sinatra tutorial (from 2008): 
http://devver.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/building-a-iphone-web-app-in-under-50-lines-with-sinatra-and-iui/

But ran into some problems with the code, for me the files aren't listed under the main heading currently. When I change `dir` to `"./public/files/"` the list is shown, but clicking a file's link results in an error page ("Sinatra doesn't know this ditty"). If I remove the `public` from the URL it will in this case work. How can I resolve the two?

Also, I get an error if with the line "use_in_file_template!", which I just comment out.
And I'm not familiar with CSS, so could someone tell me where I can the color of the text?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'pathname'

get "/" do
  dir = "./files/"
  @links = Dir[dir+"*"].map { |file|
    file_link(file)
  }.join
  erb :index
end

helpers do

  def file_link(file)
    filename = Pathname.new(file).basename
    "<li><a href='#{file}' target='_self'>#{filename}</a></li>"
  end

end

use_in_file_templates!

__END__

@@ index
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "/stylesheets/iui.css";</style>
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="/javascripts/iui.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="toolbar">
    <h1 id="pageTitle"></h1>
    </div>
    <ul id="home" title="Your files, sir." selected="true">
       <%= @links %>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, sinatra (as many other web servers) assumes that `public` is a root directory for static files and it just does not use it when accessing files/dirs in it. So, in your case, you could change (add `public` to path when get list of files and remove it when generate links to them) some lines in your code:

```
get "/" do
  dir = "public/files/"
  @links = Dir[dir+"*"].map { |file|
    file_link(file)
  }.join
  erb :index
end

helpers do
  def file_link(file)
    filename = Pathname.new(file).basename
    "<li><a href='#{file.sub('public','')}' target='_self'>#{filename}</a></li>"
  end
end
```

Comment: that's interesting i thought there was more coherence between the two, thanks for the answer!